# Android Service required to run in background until the app is killed

Tags: java, android, android-service, background-service

I have been reading Android docs and I feel I am bit lost and confused.

What is the type of service I need to use in Android, so that I can keep running my code even when the app is paused or minimized for prolonged period.

**I am not interested in running the service if the app is closed.** I want to run small piece of code that will run when app is in foreground or background, but not killed.

Comment: YOu can Run Service in sticky mode, So even your app is in background It will be running in background

Comment: use a foreground service (`Service#startForeground()` method)

Comment: You can try it with `WorkManager` library.

Comment: @pskink Are you sure? startForeground is a good idea? I don't want it to run forever. only if the app is alive in background or open in foreground.

Comment: ok so use "bound service" pattern

Comment: @AliAhmed sticky mode will re-run the service after it has been killed. isn't? when the service is killed by Android System due to lack of resource. Does it also kills the app? my confusion is mainly if service being killed has to do with app killed or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a bound `Service`. The `Service` will stop after all the bound clients disconnect. Your `Activity` binds to the `Service` and when your `Activity` is killed or finished, you unbind and the `Service` stops. If Android kills off the `Activity`, the bound connection is also shut down and your `Service` will stop.